# What verbs collocate with policy?

Tags: vocabulary, collocations

What verbs collocate with policy?
**Make** a policy? **Develop** a policy?

> The government should make a a policy to reduce the number of cars.

Does this sound correct?

Comment: You can use [this](https://inspirassion.com/en/) collocation dictonary to find collocations for nouns, verbs...etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many verbs that can logically take ***policy*** as an object. The meaning will be different in each case.

One might **set out** a policy. This means to explain, preferably thoroughly and clearly, what the policy is. It can apply to a proposed policy as well as one that is actually being put into force. In the case of organisations that have policies of primarily rhetorical value rather than practical, such as a political party (especially one not in control of government), it may be the most formal thing done with a policy. **Set forth** would be largely synonymous in this context. For the meaning of explanation, you could also just use **explain**.

One might **formulate** or **develop** a policy. This refers to the process of coming up with the policy, and may involve several drafts, consultations and so on.

One might **adopt**, **establish**, or **promulgate** a policy. This refers to putting a policy into force or making it official.

Once a policy has been adopted, it might be **enforced**. This is to take action under a policy to ensure that it is not violated.

To **make** policy could apply to formulating/developing it, or to adopting it. To **write** a policy is to set out policy in concrete written form, which may involve developing it as well. To **revise** a policy is, as one might expect, to change it in some way.

To **violate** a policy is to act contrary to it.

There are certainly other verbs that could be used, but these are the ones I think would be most often used in relation to policy.

Comment: One can adhere to a policy (act in accordance with it).

Comment: How about "impose" or "introduce"? Are they good?

Answer (score 0):

Both of those are fine and almost identical connotatively.

Comment: Why? Could you provide explanation and/or basis?

Comment: There isn't really a reason.   Sometimes in language, similar words are slightly different in context.  In this case, they are extremely close, and interchangeable.   If it was a snap decision that did not require any thought or work to enact, "develop" would be less appropriate:  "I'm going to make a no-complaining policy in my house" or "I'm going to enact a no-complaining policy" rather than "I'm going to develop....":   'develop' implies it's a little bit of work.   But the policy in the question would require work, so it's OK.